# Which redirect type to use?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have found a page :
http://www.bugatti-collection.com/login.php

which redirects to :
http://www.bugatti-collection.com/cookie_usage.php

using 302, shouldn't this page use 301 redirection?

Let me know what do you think about that.

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 0):

No because 301 is for **moved permanently**.

If you're moved to that page is because your browser does not support cookies (or they are disabled). It means that the login page has **not** been moved to cookie_usage page and if you enable cookies you can access to the original page directly.

Comment: ok so in that case some people who have cookies enabled will get to tis page without being redirected whereas those with cookies disabled need to be redirected using 302 in that case?

Comment: Yes, right! It's meaningless for end-users but it's friendly for search engines. Read this: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105

Comment: well in that case its OK, but normally 302 is not Search engine friendly...anyway thx for help much appreciated

Comment: It is but with different meaning. A search engine shouldn't update all links and scores because a temporary redirect but it should with a permanent redirect.

Comment: yep, anyway in that case any of these pages(and their links if there are any) matter to SE anyway

Comment: I **guess** SE won't follow the redirect.